# Get the column (field) name from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I do have a problem with this array:-

```
array(1) { ["fdata"]=> array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#19 (4) { ["Type ID"]=> string(4) "ET01" ["Type Name"]=> string(30) "Teaching " ["Type Code"]=> string(2) "T " ["Type Status"]=> string(10) "Active " } [1]=> object(stdClass)#20 (4) { ["Type ID"]=> string(4) "ET02" ["Type Name"]=> string(30) "Non Teaching " ["Type Code"]=> string(2) "N " ["Type Status"]=> string(10) "Active " } [2]=> object(stdClass)#21 (4) { ["Type ID"]=> string(4) "ET03" ["Type Name"]=> string(30) "Contract " ["Type Code"]=> string(2) "C " ["Type Status"]=> string(10) "Locked " } [3]=> object(stdClass)#22 (4) { ["Type ID"]=> string(4) "ET04" ["Type Name"]=> string(30) "Short Contract " ["Type Code"]=> string(2) "SC" ["Type Status"]=> string(10) "Active " } }
```

How can i get the column names? That is Type ID, Type Name etc from this array? I am using php

Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear enough... you even didn't specify what language you're using?

Comment: @ vitozev I am using php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you're planning your program. For example, you can take it from a `foreach`:

```
foreach($MyArray["fdata"] AS $i => $fdata) {
   foreach($fdata AS $key => $value) {
      echo "$i: $key: $value\n";
   }
}
```

You can also use `array_keys` to get an array of all keys http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php :

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r( array_keys( (array) ($MyArray["fdata"][0]) ));
echo "</pre>";
```

Note that you need to typecast with `(array)` because your data is an object, not an array.

Note 2: I've called the variable containing the data as $MyArray (you didn't provided its name).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you would like to list object properties. Have you tried [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) function? or casting to an array
`array_keys((array)$obj)`?

Or you could use reflection